# How to compare date columns ignoring time in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

Currently the start and end dates are stored in this format (`2019-11-22 10:04:32.878`, `2019-11-22 10:10:24.97`) respectively.

How can I compare only the dates and ignore time?

```
select *
from employee 
where   cs.startDate <> cs.endDate
```

Answer (score 3):

Just cast to date, it will trim the time part:

```
select * 
from employee 
where CAST(cs.startDate as DATE) <> CAST(cs.endDate as DATE)
```

Using `cast()` for this purpose is explicitly stated in the [official Microsoft documentation for Cast and Convert](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#i-converting-date-and-time-data-types), under Examples, item `I`.